# A Boring Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

What is the one-word solution to the following riddle?

> Backward in your leg, forward in red ink.
>   Stung, piece and digit. What is the link?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The answer is

> **BIT**

*Backward in your leg*

> The word appears in reverse in **TIB**IA, which is a bone in your leg.

*Forward in red ink*

> In accounting, red ink indicates a DE**BIT**.

*Stung*

> If you are stung by an insect, you might also say you are **BIT**TEN.

*Piece*

> A small piece of something is a **BIT**.

*Digit*

> In binary, a digit (1 or 0) is called a **BIT**.

TITLE: *A Boring Riddle*

> For boring, or drilling, you use a **BIT** on the end of the drill.

Comment: So quickly solved! I'll try not to be bitter.

Comment: I think you mean **BIT**ter...   ;)

Comment: @HughMeyers I liked the riddle.  It's a good example of a riddle that is not "too broad."  Once I had the correct answer, there was no doubt that's what it was.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain You went through the effort of concealing spoilers in your answer only to have a major spoiler in your comment above ;)

Comment: @AmruE.  I put spoilers in the answer in case someone happens upon the answer before they've had a chance to try to solve the riddle themselves.  I don't assume that someone who doesn't want to know the answer is going to be perusing the comments on a spoilered answer.

Comment: I don't even scroll down until I've tried to solve the problem myself, so it didn't bother me personally, but it might be helpful to not put the unspoilered answer in bold caps. It tends to draw the eye by accident, even if someone was just trying to scroll down to the answer box or something. Then again, it might not be helpful. Just a thought.